# How to get partial string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find all the users in the table that have this pattern

```
0123456789@gmail.com
0234567980@outlook.com
0234566666@live.gov
```

I only know the first 10 digits, the email address can be different.

I did something like this, but I get nothing back

```
   select * 
   from table where
        substr(user_identifier, 1,10) in (
        '0123456789','0234567980', '0234566666');
```

Is there another way that I can capture this data in oracle?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a comment that a real answer, but with your sample data your code works well:

```
SQL> with someTable(user_identifier) as
  2  (
  3      select '0123456789@gmail.com' from dual union all
  4      select '0234567980@outlook.com' from dual union all
  5      select '0234566666@live.gov' from dual union all
  6      select '02345__XX__66666@live.gov' from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9  from someTable where
 10      substr(user_identifier, 1,10) in ('0123456789','0234567980', '0234566666');

USER_IDENTIFIER
----------------------
0123456789@gmail.com
0234567980@outlook.com
0234566666@live.gov

3 rows selected.
```

Say you have a table like this:

```
create table someTable(user_identifier ) as 
    select '0123456789@gmail.com' from dual union all
    select '0234567980@outlook.com' from dual union all
    select '0234566666@live.gov' from dual union all
    select '02345__XX__66666@live.gov' from dual

SQL> select * from someTable;

USER_IDENTIFIER
-------------------------
0123456789@gmail.com
0234567980@outlook.com
0234566666@live.gov
02345__XX__66666@live.gov

4 rows selected.
```

Your query would give

```
USER_IDENTIFIER
-------------------------
0123456789@gmail.com
0234567980@outlook.com
0234566666@live.gov

3 rows selected.
```

What do you need instead?

Comment: thanks. The problem is that I do not know the email extention. I only know the first 10 digits.

Comment: I can't get the point; say you have a table with the data you showed, plus one record with a string like 'XXX'; in this case your code would give the 3 records you showed, and not the 'XXX' string. What do you need instead?

Comment: I have a table with millions of records. I need to find some specific records, from that table, but I only know their first 10 digits.

Comment: I tried to create a sample table, can you please explain  what you need to get and why your code is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *specific* set of 'first ten digits', and that set is subject to change (and I'll bet that ultimately it *is* subject to change) then put the values in a table and reference it in your query:

```
create table my_lookup as
select '1234567890' email_user from dual union all
select '2345678901' from dual union all
select '3456789012' from dual;

select * 
from email_table 
where substr(user_identifier, 1,10) in (select email_user from my_lookup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are other ways to write the query, e.g.:

```
where user_identifier like '0123456789@%'
   or user_identifier like '0234567980@%'
   or user_identifier like '0234566666@%'
```

but your query has a better readabilty in my opinion. Its only issue may be lack of speed, because the DBMS must scan the whole table to find the strings matching the desired substrings.

In order to speed it up, you should provide a function index on the expression used:

```
create index idx_substr on mytable ( substr(user_identifier, 1,10) );
```

Thus the DBMS can find the few rows almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for EdStevens' answer, but would write it this way and remove the subquery.  Writing it here as an answer due to lack of formatting in comments.

```
select * 
from email_table et
  join my_lookup ml
    on ml.email_user = substr(et.user_identifier, 1,10);
```

It would be interesting to do some timings on the different ways of writing this to see if this really matters.  You may need a function based index of `substr(et.user_identifier, 1,10)` on email_table if it is millions of rows.